# How to add "^" after every character in a string

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have a string like `abc123` and i want to insert `^` after every character in the string.

I already tried messing with the code below, but it seems like this only work with nummers and not with letters.

`Test = abc123 
 MsgBox, % RegExReplace(Test, "s).*?(\d{1}).*?(?=\d{1}|$)", "$1^")`

I expect the output to be `a^b^c^1^2^3^`, but it is `1^2^3^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only working with numbers because you're only matching numbers (\d). If you want to match every character you have to use a point. Try this:

```
MsgBox % RegExReplace(Test, "(.)", "$1^")
```

[More information](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#Common)